# Change Ceph Container Placement (Docker)

Tags: docker, ansible, containers, virtual-machine, ceph

I have deployed a ceph cluster using this [URL from REDHAT](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_ceph_storage/3/html/container_guide/deploying-red-hat-ceph-storage-in-containers).
It has 3 MON containers running in 3 different VMs, 2 MDS container in 2 different VMs and 4 OSD containers where 2 OSDs are placed in one VM and rest are in another VM.

It is working fine. But due to some project requirement, I have to change this placement, like moving mon container to a new VM or VM containing OSD/MDS, so on for all.
I have tries export-import method but due to ceph config change it won't work as new added mons where out of cluster.

What is the best method to do it? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Typical practice to 'move' a monitor in Ceph is to create a new monitor in the cluster on the new host, then remove the old monitor from the cluster.

The process of adding and removing monitor instances is covered in the [Adding/Removing Monitors](https://docs.ceph.com/docs/mimic/rados/operations/add-or-rm-mons/) in the documentation